# LLVM Function * getParent() fails after reading Module from mmap

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I use mmap to load the IR file into the memory. But after I did so, I could not get the module name by F->getParent()->getName() API. Could anybody give me some hint? The relevant code are as follows:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < InputFilenames.size(); ++i) {
    /*Use mmap to load files into memory*/
    StringRef MName MName = StringRef(strdup(InputFilenames[i].data()));
    if ((fd = open(MName.str().c_str(), O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        perror(MName.str().c_str());
    }

    if ((fstat(fd, &sb)) == -1) {
        errs() << "stat:\n";
        perror(MName.str().c_str());
        continue;
    }
    else {
        if (sb.st_mode & S_IFDIR) {
          continue;
        }
    }

    if ((mapped = (char *)mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                  MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (void *)-1) {
        perror("mmap");
        OP << MName.str() << " not mapped.\n";
    }
    close(fd);
    /*Get IR Module from memory buffer*/
    std::string IRString(mapped, mapped + sb.st_size);
    std::unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer> memBuffer = 
                 MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(IRString);
    MemoryBuffer *mem = memBuffer.release();
    std::unique_ptr<Module> M = parseIR(mem->getMemBufferRef(), Err, *LLVMCtx);

    Module *Md = M.release();
    for (auto curFref = Md->getFunctionList().begin(), 
              endFref = Md->getFunctionList().end(); 
              curFref != endFref; ++curFref) {
        if (curFref->empty())
            continue;
        /*"curFref->getParent()->getName()" prints nothing. */
        errs() << "--" << curFref->getName() 
               << " from Module : "<<curFref->getParent()->getName()<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think parseIR() is the wrong function, it'll parse the textual format, not a bitcode file. The one you want is called [parseBitcodeFile()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm.html#a218253c2b7611e7274db6e8f210b1471). Maybe like this:

```
auto buffer = MemoryBuffer::getFile(…);
if(buffer) {
  auto bitcode = llvm::parseBitcodeFile(buffer.get()->getMemBufferRef(),
                                        getContext());
  if(bitcode) {
    module = std::move(bitcode.get());
```

You *have* to add error handling, the `if()` tests are critically necessary. There's a [very nice pointer-like class in LLVM](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Expected.html) that only lets you dereference the "pointer" after you've checked that it's okay. So add the error handling in the way you want it, feel virtuous, and have a nice day.

Comment: Seems still some problems... I use it as ```std::unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer> memBuffer = MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(IRString);
MemoryBuffer *mem = memBuffer.release();
Expected<std::unique_ptr<Module> > ModuleOrErr = parseBitcodeFile(mem->getMemBufferRef(), *LLVMCtx);
if (ModuleOrErr) {
    M = std::move(ModuleOrErr.get());
}``` Anyway, I have stored the information in another place.